# Windows API wont quit

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-interface

For some reason after I close this window my program wont exit and goes into an infinite loop.  The solution to this problem seems to be changing GetMessage(&message, handel, 0, 0) to GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0).  However I don't understand why this is.  Can somebody please explain.  Also I don't see why I call UpdateWindow(handel) since the window will show without it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK EventHandler(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE inst, HINSTANCE prev, PSTR args, int cmd)
{
    MSG message;
    HWND handel;
    WNDCLASS win_class;

    win_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    win_class.cbClsExtra = 0;
    win_class.cbWndExtra = 0;
    win_class.lpszClassName = "Window";
    win_class.hInstance = inst;
    win_class.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DDKSHADOW);
    win_class.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    win_class.lpfnWndProc = EventHandler;
    win_class.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    win_class.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    RegisterClass(&win_class);
    handel = CreateWindow(win_class.lpszClassName, "Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 350, 250, NULL, NULL, inst, NULL);
    ShowWindow(handel, cmd);
    UpdateWindow(handel);

    //Loop does not end.
    while(GetMessage(&message, handel, 0, 0))
    {
         cout << "LOOP" << endl;
         DispatchMessage(&message);
    }
    return WM_QUIT;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK EventHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static long long count = 0;
    count++;
    cout << "CALL #" << count << endl;
    if(msg == WM_DESTROY)
    {
         PostQuitMessage(0);
         return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: You could make the question more interesting by asking why you'd *ever* pass a non-NULL handle.

Answer (score 2):

`WM_QUIT` is not sent to any window, just placed in the thread's message queue with no `HWND`, that's why it doesn't match your filter.

Comment: [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is misleading, though. "Note that GetMessage always retrieves WM_QUIT messages, no matter which values you specify for wMsgFilterMin and wMsgFilterMax." As this question and your answer show, it isn't always retrieved. However, whether it's retrieved doesn't depend on wMsgFilterMin and wMsgFilterMax.

Comment: @hvd: I interpreted that statement as "The wMsgFilterMin and wMsgFilterMax parameters do not affect WM_QUIT handling", but I agree it's misleading (or at best ambiguous).

Comment: Although I can easily see the misunderstanding, the documentation is correct.  If one manually posted `WM_QUIT` to the particular window, then code using the HWND and filters would retrieve it, even though it didn't match the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [GetMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644936%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [PostQuitMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSDN

If the parameter `hWnd` of `GetMessage` function is NULL, GetMessage retrieves messages for any window that belongs to the current thread, and any messages on the current **thread's message queue whose hwnd value is NULL**.

The PostQuitMessage function posts a WM_QUIT message to the **thread's message queue**, not to the current window.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good opportunity to exercise your "search-the-MSDN-documentation" abilities:

First, let's look up the documentation for [`WM_QUIT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Indicates a request to terminate an application, and is generated when
>   the application calls the PostQuitMessage function. This message
>   causes the GetMessage function to return zero.
>
> ...
>
> The **WM_QUIT** message is not associated with a window and therefore will
>   never be received through a window's window procedure. It is retrieved
>   only by the **GetMessage** or **PeekMessage** functions.

Then, let's look up the documentation for [`GetMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Retrieves a message from the calling thread's message queue. The
>   function dispatches incoming sent messages until a posted message is
>   available for retrieval.
>
> ...
>
> hWnd [in, optional] Type: **HWND**
>
> A handle to the window whose messages are to be retrieved. The window
>   must belong to the current thread.
>
> If hWnd is **NULL**, GetMessage retrieves messages for any window that
>   belongs to the current thread, and any messages on the current
>   thread's message queue whose hwnd value is NULL (see the MSG
>   structure). Therefore if hWnd is NULL, both window messages and thread
>   messages are processed.

*Therefore, you want to use `NULL` as the window handle for `GetMessage()`, not `handel`, since `WM_QUIT` is not associated with any window.*

There's [plenty more information about how Windows programs typically handle messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) also from MSDN.

---

As the side note, the message for window close events is [`WM_CLOSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which in turn causes your window to be destroyed by default. `WM_DESTROY` means your window is already on it's way to being destroyed. So if you want to intercept the close event (say to ask your user to save any changes), you would handle the `WM_CLOSE` event.

Also, as shown in the `GetMessage()` documentation, you should actually have your `GetMessage()` loop look like this:

```
BOOL bRet;

while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, hWnd, 0, 0 )) != 0)
{ 
    if (bRet == -1)
    {
        // handle the error and possibly exit
    }
    else
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
}
```

Because `GetMessage()` can actually return 1, 0, or -1 (despite it returning a `BOOL`).

Comment: Recommended reading: [When will GetMessage return -1?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/22/10404367.aspx) (So no, the loop does not need to look like that.)

Comment: @hvd: The Old New Thing, while it's a fantastic blog, is not official documentation. Also, note that it never returns -1 only under certain circumstances (albeit the most common one and probably only sensible one). I prefer to write programs that are as robust as possible, and it doesn't hurt to test against -1.

Comment: Your answer says to call it as `GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)`, which is precisely that certain circumstance under which you'll never get a return value of -1. It's fine if you want to check anyway, I wouldn't say your loop is wrong, just that it's unnecessary here.

Comment: @hvd: I agree with you. I would like to see the docs updated to reflect that, just so I don't have to also link to Raymond Chen's blog whenever I have to link to MSDN as well.